# nginx not using proxy cache and cloudfront

Tags: caching, nginx, reverse-proxy, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to cache static files on a server, rather than going to the 'upstream' server each time. This upstream server happens to be Cloudfront,

Here is my nginx configuration:

nginx.conf http context:

```
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$host$request_uri";
proxy_cache_path /var/spool/nginx levels=1:1 keys_zone=oly_zone:1000m;
proxy_cache_use_stale updating;
proxy_cache_valid 200 301 302 10m;
proxy_cache_valid any 10s;
proxy_cache oly_zone;
```

website.conf:

```
location /gameimages/stock/ {
  proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
  proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
  add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
  proxy_cache_valid 404 1s;
  proxy_cache_valid any 15d;
  proxy_cache oly_zone;

   proxy_pass http://d34sdfsfsadfasdfmhbsdafirsdfsdffelaut.cloudfront.net/;
}
```

I thought this worked, but an example response header shows this:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Age:11515
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:11577
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Mon, 08 Aug 2016 19:25:16 GMT
ETag:"57a47349-2d39"
Last-Modified:Fri, 05 Aug 2016 11:06:49 GMT
Server:nginx/1.4.1
Via:1.1 3ba457b8dbcd4sadfsdfe93515e26caad.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id:N0Dlk5c28sdfsf5Cvfskb3-T6PRBfSXfEPsdfasfuOLW7SHa1hjQ==
X-Cache:Hit from cloudfront
X-Proxy-Cache:HIT
```

It seems to be hitting both CloudFront and the cache on the server. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

If issue is still actual - I have found an solution.
Generally CloudFront should be excluded from assets loading path and S3 bucket should be used directly as data source.

Solution: https://dpb587.me/blog/2015/06/20/using-nginx-to-reverse-proxy-and-cache-s3-objects.html

I my case only one line had to be added to get cache magic working:

```
    # use google as dns
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
```

Also sometimes SELinux requres some tuning to prevent nginx  (13: Permission denied) errors:

```
sudo setsebool httpd_can_network_connect on -P
sudo semanage permissive -a httpd_t
```